# Issue Parsing JSON string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, parsing

I'm a java developer, new to javascript and have a JSON string coming from a WebService that needs to be parsed in JavaScript

JSON String:

```
{
  "myArrayList": [
      {
         "myHashMap": {
               "firstName": "Clara",
               "name": "Housing and Community Development"
          }
      },
     {
         "myHashMap": {
               "firstName": "Nick",
               "name": "Housing and Community Development"
         }
     }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following to parse the data but always get 'undefined'. The webservice retrieves the text as above in string format.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:7001/WS/Users?Id=35",
    function (jsonData)
    {
       for (var counter in jsonData.myArrayList) {
            alert(jsonData.myArrayList[counter]['name'])
       }
   });
```

However the alert always displays 'undefined'. Any help on resolving this would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be overlooking the `myHashMap` property. Also `for...in` is problematic with arrays if the order matters.  You’re better off with `forEach` or `for...of`.

Comment: Thanks @MarkMeyer. alert((jsonData.myArrayList[counter]['myHashMap']).firstName); worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below snipped worked:

(jsonData.myArrayList[counter]['myHashMap']).firstName;

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) should help you with the deserialization:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('[{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}]');
```

`obj[0].name` should help you get the name.

Answer (score 1):

you can acces it by arraylist[i].[harshmap] where this line can be put inside a loop and it will get all the values iteratively.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the data in the order it was inserted?

Comment: yup, use myArrayList[i].[myHarshship].[firstName],myArrayList[i].[myHarshship].[name]

Answer (score 1):

This example destructures the object and maps the resulting array

```js
        var dta = 
        {
          "myArrayList": [
              {
          "myHashMap": {
            "firstName": "Clara",
            "name": "Housing and Community Development"
                  }
              },
             {
           "myHashMap": {
           "firstName": "Nick",
            "name": "Housing and Community Development"
                 }
             }
          ]
        }
       const { myArrayList } = dta
       function parse() {
        myArrayList.map(list => {
       alert(list.myHashMap.name)
    })
    }
    parse()
```